# Ruby extract single key value from first block in json

Tags: ruby

I'm parsing a very large json output from an application API and end up with a ruby array similar to the sanitized version below:

```
{"log_entries"=>
  [{"id=>"SDF888B2B2KAZZ0AGGB200",
    "type"=>"warning",
    "summary"=>"Things happened",
    "created"=>"2017-07-11T18:40:31Z",
    "person"=>
      {"id"=>"44bAN8",
       "name"=>"Harry"}
    "system"=>"local",
    "service"=>"syslog"
  {"id=>"HMB001NBALLB81MMLLABLK",
    "type"=>"info",
    "summary"=>"Notice",
    "created"=>"2017-06-02T11:23:21Z",
    "person"=>
      {"id"=>"372z1j",
       "name"=>"Sally"}
    "system"=>"local",
    "service"=>"syslog"}]},
"other"=>200,
"set"=>0,
"more"=>false,
"total"=nil}
```

I just need to be able to print the value of the "created" key only in the first block. Meaning, when the program exits, I need it to print "2017-07-11T18:40:31Z." I've googled a lot but wasn't successful in finding anything.  I've tried something like:

```
puts ["log_entries"]["id"]["created"]
```

My expectation was to print all of them to start *somewhere* and even that yields an error. Forgive me, I don't use ruby much.

Comment: Invalid Ruby:((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `log_entries` is an array you can just access the first element and get its `created` value.

Assuming the variable `result` holds the whole hash (the JSON you parse from the API):

```
puts result['log_entries'][0]['created']
```

will print out the first date. Now you might want to guard that for cases where `log_entries` empty, so wrap it in a `if`:

```
if result['log_entries'].any?
  puts result['log_entries'][0]['created']
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not in valid format. But assuming you have the right format, following should work

```
result["log_entries"].collect{|entry| entry["created"]}
=> ["2017-07-11T18:40:31Z", "2017-06-02T11:23:21Z"]
```

Above code will collect all the created date and give you an array